# Wordpress, retrieving post value

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I need to add few static values like how we do in property files in java.

How can I do the same in Wordpress?

I tried POST approch, but I am not able to retrieve the post value in my front end.

Can anyone please suggest?

I tried retrieving post as below:

```
$args = array(
    'slug' => 'cpurl',
    'post_type' => 'cpurl',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
print_r ($my_posts);
```

shows empty array

Comment: Have you saved your posts as draft or have you published them?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I don't know why it isn't working for you. I think you have published your posts but in $args array you are using draft for post_status while as you should be using publish for post_status.

Answer (score 0):

```
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $postTitle . "'" );
$content_post = get_post($postid);
$cpUrl = $content_post->post_content;
```

used teh above code to fetch post content, using content title which was available